# FuzzyWuzzy String Matching - Case Sensitivity

Tags: python, case-insensitive, fuzzy-search, fuzzywuzzy

I'm using the [FuzzyWuzzy String Matching module from SeatGeek](http://seatgeek.com/blog/dev/fuzzywuzzy-fuzzy-string-matching-in-python).

I find that when using the token_set_ratio search algorithm, small differences in case gives wildly differing results.

For example, if I am looking for the phrase "I am eating" in a file, I get a 100% match. But if the phrase is "i am eating", just the change in case of ONE letter, gives me a 65% match.

Is there any way to make the algorithm case insensitive?

Comment: you could just use `.upper` on everything?

Answer (score 3):

token_set_ratio() is case insensitive by default.

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
fuzz.token_set_ratio("I am eating", "i am eating")
=> 100
```

Comment: Why this answer has -1 ? As far as i see it is saying the truth - it is case insensitive by default (kwarg token_process=False would make it case sensitive)

Comment: @SarunasAzna I can only make a presumption for whomever did the -1, but the answer states it is case sensitive, rather than insensitive. There are also other differences with token_set_ratio beyond just case sensitivity.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, you probably were using Ratio and not TokenSetRatio...

Answer (score 0):

If you go through the raw code of `fuzz` [here](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy/blob/9a4bc22c7483198fcb96afacc42f5f700fb803ed/fuzzywuzzy/fuzz.py) , you would find that `fuzz.token_set_ratio` converts strings to lower case before doing the sequence matching .

Further, you may want to check this stackoverflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31806695/when-to-use-which-fuzz-function-to-compare-2-strings) from SeatGeek engineer for better clarity on ratio usage.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I just converted the strings that I am comparing to lowercases:

```
fuzz.token_set_ratio("I am eating".lower(), "i am eating".lower())
```

This gives me a score of 100