# Fuzzywuzzy scores for sentences w/no overlapping words are higher than those with some overlap?

Tags: python, fuzzywuzzy

I am using fuzzywuzzy to calculate the similarity between two sentences.  Here are some results that make no sense to me:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

s1 = "moist tender pork loin chop"
s2 = "corn bicolor"
fuzz.token_sort_ratio(s1,s2)
```

This gives me a score of 41.  On the other hand:

```
s1 = "store cut sweet yellow corn tray"
s2 = "corn bicolor"
fuzz.token_sort_ratio(s1,s2)
```

gives me a score of 18.

How can a score between two sentences that do actually have an overlapping word ("corn" in this case) be lower than the score for the sentences with no overlapping words?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't know why. But you can use `token_set_ratio`, it outputs `50` for the second example. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/31806695/304209.

Answer (score 2):

[Fuzzywuzzy](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy) is implemented using Levenshtein distance. From the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance):

> Informally, the Levenshtein distance between two words is the minimum number of single-character edits (insertions, deletions or substitutions) required to change one word into the other.

**EDIT**
As was pointed out by @dennis-golomazov. There are important detail differences between token_sort_ratio and token_set_ratio.

token_sort_ratio has four steps:

1. Split string into tokens
2. Sort tokens
3. Call Levenshtein ratio from https://github.com/ztane/python-Levenshtein on the sorted tokens.
4. Return the ratio * 100

Notice that this algorithm doesn't care about partial matches

When these steps happen on your string, the code essentially becomes:

```
from Levenshtein import StringMatcher as sm

s1 = "chop loin moist tender pork"
s2 = "bicolor corn"

m = sm.StringMatcher(None, s1, s2)
print(int(m.ratio() * 100))

s1 = "corn cut store sweet tray yellow"
s2 = "bicolor corn"

m = sm.StringMatcher(None, s1, s2)
print(int(m.ratio() * 100))
```

You'll notice that these ratios match the ones you saw in your test case.

So, you would definitely want to use fuzz.token_set_ratio as it accounts for the fact that corn is in both strings and can match accordingly