# how fuzzywuzzy python works - when there is no matching words between sentences?

Tags: python, nlp, fuzzywuzzy, sentence-similarity

I am using fuzzywuzzy match to find similarity between sentences.

when I compare these two sentences- 'user attempts login' and 'acceptance criteria'

fuzz.token_set_ratio('user attempts login', 'acceptance criteria')

it gives me a score of 42 .

could someone please help me understand how we get score of 42 when there are no matching words ??

Comment: Check out [When to use which fuzz function to compare 2 strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31806695/when-to-use-which-fuzz-function-to-compare-2-strings)

Answer (score 0):

### Steps of the Algorithm

Token_set_ratio performs the following steps:

1. split sentence and remove duplicates
2. create three lists of

   - `remainder1` = words that are only in the first sentence
   - `remainder2` = words that are only in the second sentence
   - `intersection` = words that are in both sentences
3. sort the words in the three lists and join the elements to a combined string

   - `sorted_remainder1`
   - `sorted_remainder2`
   - `sorted_intersection`
4. join the strings in the following way:

   - `combined1` = <sorted_intersection><sorted_remainder1>
   - `combined2` = <sorted_intersection><sorted_remainder2>
5. calculate the following similarities:

   - fuzz.ratio(`sorted_intersection`, `combined1`)
   - fuzz.ratio(`sorted_intersection`, `combined2`)
   - fuzz.ratio(`combined1`, `combined2`)
6. return the maximum of those similarities

### Example

For the strings `user attempts login` and `acceptance criteria` this leads to the following result:

```py
remainder1 = ['user', 'attempts', 'login']
remainder2 = ['acceptance', 'criteria']
intersection = []
sorted_remainder1 = 'attempts login user'
sorted_remainder2 = 'acceptance criteria'
combined1 = 'attempts login user'
combined2 = 'acceptance criteria'

fuzz.ratio(sorted_intersection, combined1) = 0
fuzz.ratio(sorted_intersection, combined2) = 0
fuzz.ratio(combined1, combined2) = 42
```

In your specific case this is a similar result to `fuzz.token_sort_ratio`, which only sorts the words in both sentences and compares them using `fuzz.ratio`.